# python manage.py startapp item doesn't work for me

Tags: python, django

I saw this command work in my django video courses but unfortunately it doesn't work for me when I enter

```
python manage.py startapp item
```

it returns an error which says :

```
  File "D:\Django\puddle\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Django\puddle\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "D:\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "D:\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Msk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'item'
```

I just tried to install this app to learn the rest of the Django course but it says the item module not found!

Comment: Did you add `item` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` before starting the app?

Comment: Yes! I actually did it, I didn't think there was a problem with it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output of the script you added `'item'` to the [**`INSTALLED_APPS`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#installed-apps) *before* starting the app.

This is not the right order, you *first* start the app, so that Django can add the module with submodules, and *then* you add it to the `INSTALLED_APPS`. So you should remove it for now, then start the app, and then add `'item'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` again.